# How to automatically re-size an image, in a div, using css?

Tags: html, css, image

When I replace the theme's image, thumb-1.jpg, with my own image, my image is not automatically re-sizing to fit the space. My image shows up twice as large as the theme's image.

What custom CSS do I use to change my image to be the same size as the theme image, so my image fits the space?

Theme I purchased: http://themeforest.net/item/grepfrut-responsive-software-html-template/3215883

HTML

```
            <h4 class="heading-icon clearfix"><img src="img/icons/heading-icon-1.png" width="40" height="40" alt="icon" class="icon-small-bg"> Three easy steps.</h4>

            <!--carousel list starts-->
            <div id="carousel" class="es-carousel-wrapper">
                <div class="es-carousel">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <div class="folio-thumb"><img src="img/preview/thumb-1.jpg" alt="image" /> <a href="img/preview/thumb-1.jpg" data-rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="This is title of Image" class="icon-zoom"></a></div>
                            <h5>......</h5>
                            <p>...... </p>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="folio-thumb"><img src="img/preview/thumb-2.jpg" alt="image" /> <a href="img/preview/thumb-2.jpg" data-rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="This is title of Image" class="icon-zoom"></a></div>
                            <h5>.... </h5>
                            <p> .....</p>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="folio-thumb"><img src="img/preview/thumb-3.jpg" alt="image" /> <a href="img/preview/thumb-3.jpg" data-rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="This is title of Image" class="icon-zoom"></a></div>
                            <h5>....</h5>
                            <p> ......</p>
                        </li>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--carousel list ends-->
```

CSS

```
.folio-thumb {
margin-bottom: 10px;
display:inline-block;
position:relative;}

.icon-zoom {
background: url(../img/zoom.png) no-repeat 0 0;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
margin-left: -50px;
margin-top: -50px;
-webkit-transition-duration: 0s;
-moz-transition-duration: 0s;
-ms-transition-duration: 0s;
-o-transition-duration: 0s;
transition-duration: 0s;
z-index: 9;
outline: none;}



.icon-zoom:hover {
background-position: 0 -100px;}
```

Comment: Are you referring to the images in the slider?

Comment: @JoshuaTerrill Yes. <img src="img/preview/thumb-1.jpg"

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the img general tag in CSS.
something like:

```
.folio-thumb img{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your image has the same proportions, I would suggest getting the image wrapper setup like this for retina displays and for responsiveness. This way it keeps it's shape based on it's container and compresses down etc. [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

### HTML

```
<div class="your-box">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" alt="" />
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.your-box {
    max-width: 200px;
}

.your-box img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

in your case, I would actually make a global class of .image-w and then you could use that site-wide like this. Anything you want to be a responsive image, just put this class as a base.

```
<div class="image-w folio-thumb">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" alt="" />
</div>

.image-w img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```